# SonicWALL TZ215 : 2 LAN interfaces and 1 WAN

Tags: switch, router, vlan, layer3, sonicwall

Here is network schema:

```
192.168.2.200 - Switch layer 2 ---|                     |--X0 LAN 192.168.2.254
                                  |---Switch layer 3 ---|
10.50.40.40 --- Swtich layer 2 ---|                     |--X6 LAN 10.50.60.1
                                                        |-- WAN
```

The layer-3 switch has multiple IP addresses: 10.50.40.1, 10.50.60.6, and 192.168.2.1.

The default route for the layer-3 switch is 0.0.0.0 for gateway 192.168.2.254.

There are three VLANs on the the layer-3 switch, and routing is enabled.

VLAN1 (192.168.2) is the default VLAN. There were 3 switches. I changed those switches to make VLANs, change network addressing, and delete all 192.168.2 addresses.

There are other VLANs, but for clarity I show only one.

**I've got these issues:**

- When machine 192.168.2.200 has 192.168.2.254 for its gateway, it can get
  to the Internet and ping 10.50.60, but it can't ping 10.50.40.*.
- Machines in 10.50.40.* have the gateway 10.50.40.1, can't get to the
  Internet, can't ping 192.168.2.254, can ping all other 192.168.2,
  but they can't make MSTSC or access network shares or nslookup the DNS (all services can't go).

**So, I've made these changes:**

- On the SonicWALL, I've added a route to access 10.50.40 with gateway
  10.50.60.6.
- Now, from 192.168.2.200, I can ping 10.50.40 and 10.50.60, but from
  192.168.2 and from 10.50.40, I can't MSTSC or network share or whatever.

**Another change:**

- On machine 192.168.1.200, I set the gateway to 192.168.2.1
- Now, all over network services are reachable for all networks. I can
  MSTSC and network share etc., but now from 192.168.2.200, I can't
  ping 10.50.60.1 (X6 interface)!
- From machine 10.50.40, I still can't ping 192.168.2.254, and I can't
  get to the Internet.

**Summary:**

- If I'm on VLAN1 (default vlan 192.168.2), I can't ping the X6
  interface.
- If I'm on VLAN4 (10.50.40), I can't ping the X0 interface, and VLAN4
  can't get to the Internet.

I don't know what's happening. Please help if you have any ideas.

**News:**

I've changed the default route on the layer-3 switch to the gateway 10.50.60.1, and now 10.50.40 can get to the Internet, but 192.168.2 can't.

It seems to be a SonicWALL issue.

Comment: Please include the relevant configurations.

Comment: I added switch layer 3 conf. Which config would you like for SonicWall? route, interfaces?

Comment: In the test you say that default route is `192.168.2.254`, but in the configuration it is `192.168.2.252`.

Comment: Yes because i made a mistake while i wrote my post. i changed  all addresses for the post :)

Comment: Please do no edit the title to include "Solved." Instead, if someone has provided an answer that resolves your question (including yourself), please consider marking it as the accepted answer. This will provide all the indication of the resolution needed. If you do not do so, your question will periodically get refreshed back to the main page, possibly distracting community members from other questions they may be able to help answer for other users. Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If the "*Switch layer 3*" truly is configured for layer-3, you should not have the same subnet on each side of the switch.  A host won't use layer-3 to talk to another device in the same subnet, that is a layer-2 function, and separating a layer-2 domain with layer-3 will cause you no end of problems.

Based on your diagram and comments, you have some serious design and configuration problems.

**Edit:**

The hosts on the VLANs should use the VLAN IP address configured on the layer-3 switch as the gateway for the host.  This will allow them to connect to other hosts on different VLANs.

The hosts addressed in the subnet of a VLAN need to be connected to a port that is in that VLAN.

The layer-3 switch, as the site router, should have its default route point to the IP address of the device which is directly connected to the Internet if you wan the hosts on the VLANs to access the Internet.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I'm pretty new on networking :) if i delete X0 interface, could it work?

Answer (score 1):

It works now. I have deleted the configuration from this post.

I have unassigned X6 on sonicwall and simply made a route to join my VLANs.
Now all machine can go to Internet and do everything.

My network design was not correct. I thought it could work like my diagram but it doesn't. So now, it works without X6.

Comment: You should accept an answer. If you don't.this question will keep popping up, looking for an answer.